# The Javascript wont run

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to develop a web page that calculates the discount price and displays on the web page itself. The main thing is to fire both the functions with the same `onclick` event, but it wont run, as far as I am beginner I don't know if the functions are wrongly written or its something else. I need to display the discount percent in one `id="discount"` and discounted price in another `id="result"`. Unable to figure out where I mess up, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function calculate() {
  var product_name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var product_price = document.getElementById('price').value;
  var select = document.getElementById("sale");
  var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selected == summer) {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.10);
  } else if (selected == newyear) {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.05);
  } else {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.15);
  }
  // body...
}

function display_sale() {
  if (selected == summer) {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 10%";
  } else if (selected == newyear) {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 5%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 15%";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
    <h1>DISCOUNT PRICE</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Price</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" pattern="([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?|0\.[0-9]*[1-9])" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Season</td>
            <td colspan="2"><select id="sale">
                  <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
                  <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
                  <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br/>
    <div  style="margin-left: 40%">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calculate();"> GET DISCOUNT PRICE</button>
    </div>
    <div id="discount">

    </div>
    <div id="result">

    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: click the button, check the developer tools console - see the error `ReferenceError: selected is not defined` - that's because you use a variable `selected` that isn't defined. hint: `summer` and `newyear` are also not defined

Comment: i have defined it in script, wont that work? if i defined using var, or i should put values inside ""?

Comment: maybe in `calculate`, but not in `display_sale`, which is called first, and regardless, the definition in `claculate` isn't availabe in display_sale anyway

Comment: the javascript executes but disappears suddenly @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, when you submit a form, the page is replaced in the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX so what should i do to fix it, remove the form tag? then the validations wont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151238/discussion-between-shivam-srivastava-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: you've accepted an answer, why are we discussing this?

Comment: because i belivew this resulted in something that is not desirable

Comment: well now its not required for any discussion its solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just define your *selected* variable out of the function scope and use strings in quotations mark (" " or ' ')

Edit: please read about scopes. you should define your *selected* variable somewhere that your functions can access it. also when you use strings in js, you should wrap them in ' ' , please double check your code , apply it , then come back here if you have any other problems.

Edit 2: also if you don't want to submit anything , don't *type="submit"* in your button element. if you want to submit the form in javascript you can set an id for your form and get the element in js and use the submit function of the element.

```js
var selected;
function calculate() {
  var product_name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var product_price = document.getElementById('price').value;
  var select = document.getElementById("sale");
  selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selected == 'summer') {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.10);
  } else if (selected == 'newyear') {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.05);
  } else {
    var discount_price = product_price - (product_price * 0.15);
  }
  // body...
}

function display_sale() {
  if (selected == 'summer') {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 10%";
  } else if (selected == 'newyear') {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 5%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The discount is 15%";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 35%"><em>DISCOUNT PRICE</em></h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Product Price</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="price" id="price"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Season</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <select id="sale">
            <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
            <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
            <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table><br/>
    <div style="margin-left: 40%">
      <button type="submit" onclick="display_sale(); calculate();"> GET DISCOUNT PRICE</button>
    </div>
    <p id="discount"></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked, but when i applied html form validation feature it just executes immediately on click and disappers, why is that happeining

Comment: check the updated answer also fix your js code, and the html as well @ShivamSrivastava